# How to move file from Alfresco Server one Absolute path to another target path using move method on java

Tags: java, alfresco

```
    Node node = session.getNodeByUUID(uuid);

    Workspace space = session.getWorkspace();
    Node targetNode = obtainNode(rootNode, "/app:company_home/app:user_homes/cm:admin/cm:test_space");

    try {

        String path = node.getPath();
        int index = path.lastIndexOf("/");
        String newPathName = path.substring(0, index);
        //newPathName = newPathName + "/" + node.getName();

        String tpath = targetNode.getPath();
        int tindex = tpath.lastIndexOf("/");
        String tnewPathName = tpath.substring(0, tindex);
        tnewPathName = tnewPathName + "/" + targetNode.getName();

        session.move(newPathName, newPathName);
        session.save();
        commit();

    } catch (ItemExistsException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (PathNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (VersionException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ConstraintViolationException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (LockException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (RepositoryException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

This code i wrote in class file is not moving from one Absolute path to targeted path in java. need to guidence with JCR 1.0.jar this example with Alfresco Server Repository

Comment: Are you absolute sure you want to go through with JCR. It's gone in the new 5.0 version :).

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be moving something from newPathName to newPathName. Shouldn't that be:

```
session.move(path, newPathName);
```